# Minmax tic-tac-toe algorithm that never loses

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, minmax

I'm trying to build a min-max algorithm for a Tic-Tac-Toe that never lose...

I try to build it from reading few sources:

1. http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax
2. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimax-algorithm-in-game-theory-set-3-tic-tac-toe-ai-finding-optimal-move/ (I built something very similar to this one).

Here is the code:
class tree:

```
def find_best_move(self,board,depth,myTurn,sign):
    """

    :param board:
    :return:
    """
    if (board.empty==[]): return None

    best_move=-(2**(board.s**2))
    m=board.empty[0]
    for move in board.empty:
        b=copy.deepcopy(board)
        b.ins(move,sign)
        if (self.is_win(b,sign) or self.is_win(b,xo.opp_sign(sign))):
            return move
        curr_move=self.minimax(b,depth,myTurn,sign)
        if (curr_move > best_move):
            best_move = curr_move
            m=move
        print(curr_move,best_move,m)

    return m #This should be the right move to do....


# *****************************************************************************************************#

def minimax(self,board,depth,myTurn,sign):
    """

    :param depth:
    :param myTurn:
    :return:
    """
    #print(depth,end='\n')
    if (self.is_win(board,sign)):
        #print("I win!")
        return (board.s**2+1) - depth
    elif (self.is_win(board,xo.opp_sign(sign))):
        #print("You win!")
        return -(board.s**2+1) + depth
    elif (board.is_full()):
        return 0

    if (myTurn):
        bestVal=-(2**700)
        for move in board.empty: #empty - the empty squares at the board 
            b = copy.deepcopy(board)
            b.ins(move, sign)
            value=self.minimax(b,depth+1,not myTurn, xo.opp_sign(sign))
            #xo.opp_sign(sign) - if function for the opposite sign: x=>o and o=>x
            bestVal = max([bestVal,value])
        return bestVal

    else:
        bestVal = (2**700)
        for move in board.empty:
            b = copy.deepcopy(board)
            b.ins(move, xo.opp_sign(sign))
            value = self.minimax(b, depth + 1, not myTurn, xo.opp_sign(sign))
            #print("opp val: ",value)
            bestVal = min([bestVal, value])
        return bestVal


# *****************************************************************************************************#
def is_win(self,board, sign):
    """
    The function gets a board and a sign.
    :param board: The board.
    :param sign: The sign (There are only two options: x/o).
    :return: True if sign "wins" the board, i.e. some row or col or diag are all with then sing. Else return False.
    """

    temp=board.s
    wins = []  # The options to win at the game.
    for i in range(1, temp + 1):
        wins.append(board.get_col(i))
        wins.append(board.get_row(i))
    wins.append(board.get_diag1())
    wins.append(board.get_diag2())

    for i in wins:
        if (self.is_same(i, sign)):
            return True
    return False



# *****************************************************************************************************#
def is_same(self, l, sign):
    """
    The function get a list l and returns if ALL the list have the same sign.
    :param l: The list.
    :param sign: The sign.
    :return: True or false
    """

    for i in l:
        if (i != sign):
            return False
    return True
```

If something is wrong at my code please tell me!

But, I always can beat this - I just need to make a "fork"
.e.g.: (I'm x, the algorithm is o)

```
xx-   
xo-   
-o-
```

And I win...
There is algorithm for making a tree that can block forks?

Comment: If you can win, it means you did not program it correctly. We have no crystal ball to see what the problem is though.

Comment: Algorithms are not necessarily off-topic here, but we need more detail. Just what algorithm did you use--saying "Minimax" is not enough. It would be best to show your code or a pseudocode representation of it at a high-to-medium level.

Comment: I put the code  - if you need other stuff - please let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three errors.

#### 1. In your *minimax* method the sign is swapped one time too many

You swap the sign in the `else` block -- for the case where *myTurn* is `False` -- but you shouldn't. You already swap the sign with each recursive call. Because of this bug, you always puts the same sign on the board during your minimax search, never the opposite one. Obviously you therefore miss all the threats of the opponent.

So change:

```
    else:
        bestVal = (2**700)
        for move in board.empty:
            b = copy.deepcopy(board)
            b.ins(move, error xo.opp_sign(sign)) # <-- bug
```

to:

```
    else:
        bestVal = (2**700)
        for move in board.empty:
            b = copy.deepcopy(board)
            b.ins(move, sign) # <-- corrected
```

#### 2. In *find_best_move* you should swap the move as you call *minimax*

And a similar bug occurs in *find_best_move*. As you go through each move, you must swap the sign when calling *minimax* in the new board, otherwise you let the same player play twice.

So change this:

```
    for move in board.empty:
        b=copy.deepcopy(board)
        b.ins(move,sign)
        if (self.is_win(b,sign) or self.is_win(b,xo.opp_sign(sign))):
            return move
        curr_move=self.minimax(b,depth,myTurn,sign) # <-- bug
```

to:

```
    for move in board.empty:
        b=copy.deepcopy(board)
        b.ins(move,sign)
        if (self.is_win(b,sign) or self.is_win(b,xo.opp_sign(sign))):
            return move
        curr_move=self.minimax(b,depth,not myTurn,xo.opp_sign(sign)) # <-- corrected
```

Note that the second condition should not be necessary: if you are the one who just moved, it is not logical that the other should come in a winning position.

#### 3. In *minimax* you don't consider the value of *myTurn* when there is win

Although you consider the value of *myTurn* to determine whether to minimise or maximise, you don't perform this operation when checking for a win.

You currently have this:

```
if (self.is_win(board,sign)):
    #print("I win!")
    return (board.s**2+1) - depth
elif (self.is_win(board,xo.opp_sign(sign))):
    #print("You win!")
    return -(board.s**2+1) + depth
elif (board.is_full()):
    return 0
```

First of all, the first `if` condition should not be true ever, because the most recent move was for the opposite sign, so that could never lead to a win for *sign*.

But to the issue: the second `if` does not look to *myTurn* to determine whether the return value should be negative or positive. It should do so to be consistent. So change the above code to this:

```
if self.is_win(board,xo.opp_sign(sign)):
    if myTurn: 
        return -(board.s**2+1) + depth
    else:
        return (board.s**2+1) - depth
elif board.is_full():
    return 0
```

#### How to call *find_best_move*

Finally, the above works if you always call *find_best_move* with the *myTurn* argument as `True`, because *find_best_move* maximises the result as can be seen from `if (curr_move > best_move)`. So, to avoid that you call it with `False`, you would better remove this argument and pass `False` to *minimax*. So:

```
def find_best_move(self,board,depth,sign): # <-- myTurn removed as argument
    # ... etc ...

        curr_move=self.minimax(b,depth,False,xo.opp_sign(sign)) # pass False
```

This way, the argument *myTurn* indicates whether the turn is to the same player as the player for which *find_best_move* was called.

#### Working Solution

With minimal code added to make it work (`Board` and `XO` classes added), the program can be seen to run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/EuVq/2).

Note that this algorithm is not optimal. It is just brute force. You could look into storing results of previously evaluated positions, doing alpha-beta pruning, etc...

Comment: Still don't work.... I can show you the moves series of the game that this algorithm loses - I'll put the number of the square from 1 (to top left corner) to 9 (the down-right corner), the tree (of this algorithm) is 'o': x->1, o->2, x->5 (the center),  o->9, x->7 (the right-down corner), and the 'x' won.... :-(   Can you know why? it's wired that the first move of the tree was not at the center....

Comment: If I have few moves that gets the same score? what should I do? I think that this makes many problems :-(

Comment: No problem! Thank you!! You want the full code? of you are OK with this?

Comment: I'm OK with this. I assume the other code is bug-free

Comment: Yes, the other code is just for representing the board and manage the game (there are few "types" of players) - and both of them are OK (I checked them...) - Thank you!!

Comment: I added the third problem & solution to my answer.

Comment: Why this is necessary? 
elif board.is_full():
    return 0

Comment: That is your own code. You should know. ;-) It is to detect a draw.

Comment: When I enter X at 6, the answer from the best move is not 9, but 5 (the center), so I cannot reproduce what you are saying.

Comment: See a simple implementation at [repl.it](https://repl.it/EuVq/2). Note that the move numbers are from 0 to 8 there, not 1 to 9.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!!